# XDMP-ELEMRIDXNOTFOUND: cts:element-values -- No element range index in MarkLogic 10 [marklogic]

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I am new to MarkLogic.

I have XML doc

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books xmlns="http://www.marklogic.com/ns/gs-books">
<book bookid="2">
<title>A Quick Path to an Application</title>
<author>
<last>Smith</last>
<first>James</first>
</author>
<publisher>Scribblers Press</publisher>
<isbn>1494-3930392-4</isbn>
<abstract>
          This book describes in detail the power of how 
          to use Java to build powerful web applications 
          that are built on the MarkLogic Server platform.
      </abstract>
</book>
</books>
```

How can I use `cts:element-values` against it?

Here is my try:  `cts:element-values(xs:QName("test"),"test")`

It gives me this error:

> [1.0-ml] XDMP-ELEMRIDXNOTFOUND: cts:element-values(fn:QName("","t"), "t") -- No element range index for t collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/ coordinate-system=wgs84
> [marklogic]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to be able to use [`cts:element-values()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-values), the element needs to have a corresponding range-index to use.

> Returns values from the specified element value lexicon(s). Value lexicons are implemented using range indexes; consequently this function requires an element range index for each element specified in the function. If there is not a range index configured for each of the specified elements, an exception is thrown.

So, in order to be able to run: `cts:element-values(xs:QName("test"),"test")`

You would first need to create a String range index for the "`test`" element (and ensure the reindexer is enabled, and allow for it to finish reindexing the docs with that element, in order to build the lexicon).

You can configure an element-range-index in the [Admin UI](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index#id_51346), programmatically with [`admin:database-add-range-element-index()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:database-add-range-element-index), and if you have an [ml-gradle](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle) project they can be added to the database configuration.

Comment: Good answer. I would like to vote thumbup, but the sys does not let me because I do not have enough reputation to vote.